# ScrolledComposite no scrollbar in JFace dialog

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am currently trying to extend a `JFace` dialog to contain a `scrolledComposite`. My code currently looks like this:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MWE extends MessageDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dialog d = new MWE(new Display().getActiveShell());
        d.open();
    }

    public MWE(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell, "MWE", null, "",
                MessageDialog.ERROR, new String[] {  "OK" }, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);
        sc.setMinSize(300, 300);
        Composite content = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
        sc.setContent(content);
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Label l = new Label(content, SWT.NONE);
            l.setText("lorem ipsum");
        }
        return parent;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that like this the size of the window just spans the full screen height, instead of being scrollable if it goes above a certain size. How do i get to scroll if the content exceeds the size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `heightHint` in the layout data for the `ScrolledComposite`:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
data.heightHint = 500;
sc.setLayoutData(data);
```

Use the computed size of the contents for the minimum size:

```
sc.setMinSize(content.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

(do this after all the content has been added to `content`)

Comment: This solution makes the content not extend over an height of 500, but unfortunalty no scrollbars appear :-(

Comment: Added setMinSize requirement